# jquery hover only to work if hovering for a certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, hover

In a list of links, I only want to activate the hover behavior for those links after the person is hovering over that link for a certain amount of time (say 1 second).  So if they happen to just pass over the link (for less than one second) I don't want the hover event to occur.

Does anyone know how to do this or have any examples of this?
Thanks!

Comment: if it's an animation, use .stop() instead. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, There is a plugin for jQuery called [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) that does what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recomend using the [hover intent jquery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) for this. It's solved this problem for me before and seems to be very well written and light.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delay in your hover chain:

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

There is also a plugin called "hoverIntent" which I would link you to if I was allowed.

Comment: why aren't you allowed? @Spencer